# How to input data in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, input, machine-learning

I have a input format like

1,ABCDSGDSDGHSDFSDFSDGSDGSDGSDHSDFS
5,KDFJSKDJGKSDJGLJSDKGJDSDGSJDKGDGG
...

I want to do the decision tree on this training sample where the number is the output, and the every character is like a feature of the sample, I try different method to input the data, I found out that the fitctree method in matlab require the X to be numerical(floating point) , so I convert the char to number(a = 1,b= 2 etc), but after that, I do not know how to spilt these digits and treat them like different features rather than a very very big number(1234...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to go is to cast directly your characters to doubles with the `double` function.

For instance:

```
% --- Definition
Xs = '1,ABCDSGDSDGHSDFSDFSDGSDGSDGSDHSDFS';
Ys = '5,KDFJSKDJGKSDJGLJSDKGJDSDGSJDKGDGG';

% ---- Prepare double input (I remove the '1,' and '5,', please check)
X = double(Xs(3:end))';
Y = double(Ys(3:end))';

% --- Perform the fit tree
m = fitctree(X, Y);
view(m,'Mode','graph')
```

In this case the letters are converted to their ASCII code, `i.e.` `A = 65`, `B = 66`, and so on, so the classification is based on the alphabetical order.

Here is the output:

[image]

Hope this helps,